# How to make conversion operator returning reference and non reference

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template class, looking something like:

```
template<class T>
class A
{
  public:
     operator T() const {  return value;}
     operator T&() { return value;}

  private:
       T value;

}
```

It seems that the operatorT() const is never called. Even in a statement like this

```
const int a = myA;
```

where myA is a  instance of A.
Is there something wrong, missing  with the above code?

Comment: Not directly related to your problem, but I think it's probably poor practice to do this. Better to make `operator T() const` return `const T&`, or make both operators return `T`. `const` objects should not have different semantics from non-`const` objects *except* that they can't be modified.

Comment: `&&` should return `T` or `T&&` on the other hand.

Answer (score 5):

The operator will take effect only when you define an object of type `const A<T>`. For example:

```
const A<int> myA;
int someInt = myA;
```

will call `operator T() const`.

And, since it's of course true - like [Benjamin Lindley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440119/benjamin-lindley) pointed out - if you access the object through a `const` reference.

Comment: Or if you access the object through a const reference.